# Kendo grid - Group by a maximum of 3 columns

Tags: jquery, arrays, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to limit grouping in my Kendo jQuery Grid to a maximum of 3 columns.
I know that I need to do this using the databound event and will need to use `grid.dataSource.group()` and remove the new column from the array. Perhaps the best way is to store the 'previous' grouping and then compare the old and new arrays to see which column is the new one, then remove that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cancel the grouping in the `group` event like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "age" },
      { field: "test" }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, test: 1 },
        { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33, test: 2 }
      ],
      schema: {
        model: { id: "id" }
      }
    },
    groupable: true,
    group: function(e) {
      if (e.groups.length > 2) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Group prevented");
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works on Firefox, I'll fix it for other browsers too, thanks